# install U-boot : error : Makefile:501: *** "System not configured - see README". Stop

Tags: image, u-boot

I try to install u-boot . I followed [ http://elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot ]

I  downloaded source form git `git clone git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git`

and get the Raspberry compiler `git clone git://github.com/raspberrypi/tools rpi-tools` and export the path.

when I try to build u-boot like they said `make -j2 -s rpi_b`
I get error `Makefile:501: *** "System not configured - see README".  Stop`

what's the keyword to configure u-boot for Raspberry???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error message clearly says: "*** "System not configured - see README", that means you haven't configured your build system, it has no idea what board you need `u-boot` built for, and details about configuration could be found in `README` file -- read it and get enlightened.

most likely the following command will do the trick:

```
make rpi_b_config
```

Comment: I want to build u-boot for Raspberry. I think that your command is for that. I launch it : Configuring for rpi_b board... 

and then when I launch make -j2 -s rpi_b  I get an other error : GEN     include/autoconf.mk.dep
cc1: error: bad value (armv5t) for -march= switch
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk
cc1: error: bad value (armv5t) for -march= switch
  CHK     include/config/uboot.release. any idea

Comment: your compiler does not understand ARM architecture, are you sure you have installed cross-compilation toolchain and did `export CROSS_COMPILE=...` ?

Comment: thanks, you're right, when I made make rpi_b_config, I forget to export the cross-compilation path.